# Update weights of keras model only based on samples that meet a condition while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lambda, model

I have an autoencoder model using keras, input and output shape is (BATCH_SIZE, 20). In the middle there is a Lambda layer that filters the data. In other words, if the batch size is 1000, there might be only 700 that comes out from the Lambda layer. Then I want to update the weights based on just these 700 samples. Is there any way to tackle this in Keras?

Comment: Use a customized loss and do the filtering (or "mask") to handle this in your loss function.  Use the 700 data for computing loss and the rest of the data loss were set to 0

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with such a situation and the way I handled was by keeping the batch dimension flexible. For example: if you are using TensorFlow define the placeholder as [None, w, h, 3] (in case of image) and develop your model. The weights have nothing to do with the batch dimensions. So,  when you decrease the size of the computations on axis = 0, the rest of the change will happen accordingly. Basically don't define any concrete batch size, keep it flexible.